# Paragraph ended before \@car was complete

Tags: latex, quarto, beamer

I try to generate a quarto presentation using the following .qmd script:

```
---
title: "Biostatistique"
author: Dr Saïd Maanan
lang: fr

format:
  beamer: 
    pdf-engine: xelatex
    theme: Boadilla
    colortheme: dove
    fonttheme: serif
    date: today
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 1
    toccolor: "red"
    include-in-header: 
      - file: preamble-beamer.tex
editor: visual
---

# Introduction et motivation

## C'est quoi la biostatistique?

Définition

:   La biostatistique est l'application des concepts et principes statistiques à des données médicales, biologiques et de santé public.

Exemple

:   -   Les effets d'un médicament.

    -   L'effet du niveau du cholestérol sur la pression artérielle.

    -   Le nombre de patients admis durant les fins de semaine aux urgences.

    -   Distribution des pandémies.

    -   L'étude sur les différentes complications dans le traitement des patients atteints du virus VIH.
```

But I get this error after compiling the .qmd file:

```
updating tlmgr

updating existing packages

compilation failed- error
Paragraph ended before \@car was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.237 \end{frame}
                  

see biostatistique.log for more information.
```

What is the reason for this error? And how can I fix it? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: We can't compile your code fragment as we don't have access to the local files you include. Without them your code compiles without error.